# I have a huge data of images and I want to resize it automatically in loop with a specific size in python

Tags: python, image, for-loop, crop, image-resizing

I have this code but I can't put it in a loop:
from PIL import Image

```
# Opens a image in RGB mode 
im = Image.open(r"imagPath.png") 

# Setting the points for cropped image 
left = 155
top = 65
right = 360
bottom = 270

# Cropped image of above dimension 
# (It will not change orginal image) 
im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) 



# Shows the image in image viewer 
im1.show()
```

it works but I want it in for loop read all the images in the folder

Comment: What is preventing you from putting it in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.listdir` to list all images in your folder, then you can iterate over them.